# Trouble converting time to UTC for highstocks

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, timezone, highcharts

I'm having the hardest time trying to convert this date from an API to UTC milliseconds. As of right now I'm displaying the dates but it's showing 7 hours ahead and going on to the next day which I don't even have data for. Here is the example format:

> 8/31/2012 9:00:00 AM

I currently have this code

```
var formattedDate = new Date(data[i].Time);
formattedDate = formattedDate.getTime();
```

which seems like it's returning the correct value type but the date is wrong. I've also tried
getUTCMilliseconds() and returns 0.

EDIT: jsfiddle example :  http://jsfiddle.net/b2NK6/

Comment: have you tried getUTCMilliseconds() ?

Comment: Yes I don't think the date object is UTC and is an hour ahead .. EDIT: It returns 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want the raw timestamp in UTC time, instead of local time?

Compare:

```
(new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 7, 31, 9, 0, 0, 0))).getTime(); /* month 7 is August */
```

with

```
(new Date(Date.parse("8/31/2012 9:00:00 AM"))).getTime();
```

When you parse the string (the second example) it applies your local timezone information when it creates the date object.  If you are in timezone -0700, then the date that is created will actually correspond to 4:00pm UTC.

But if you create the date object by explicitly saying that you are specifying the UTC value, it will give you 9:00am UTC, which corresponds to 2:00am in timezone -0700.

*Edited to give clearer and more correct code example.*

Comment: This just converts the time to "Fri Aug 31 2012 09:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"

Comment: ah alright I see what your saying how can I make it more dynamic and work with this

http://jsfiddle.net/ecHpX/

Comment: got it working just created a date before hand to call from inside the UTC one so i could do t.getFullYear(), t.getMonth() etc

Comment: If you use the get methods, be sure to use getUTCFullYear(), getUTCMonth(), and so on.  Think about the case of "Dec 31 2012 11:00:00 pm -0700" to understand why!

Comment: As an alternative, you can also explicitly add the UTC timezone ("+0000") to the date string, like "8/31/2012 9:00:00 AM +0000", and pass it to Date.parse().

Comment: So I tried using UTC methods and it was returning results like before starting at 4pm I believe its because of the date object.

This is what i have now
                    var t = new Date(data[i].Time);
                    var formattedDate = (new Date(Date.UTC(t.getFullYear(), t.getMonth(), t.getDay(), t.getHours(), 0, 0, 0))).getTime();   Which is returning the right time and everything it's just saying aug 5th instead of 31st

Comment: getDay() returns day of the week (0 - 6).  You want getDate().  Check out http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp versus http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getdate.asp.  Also see above about getUTC versus just get.

Comment: got it working by just using HighCharts.setOption({global:{useUTC:false}}); and then just using getTime(); on the date it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
var dateString = "8/31/2012 9:00:00 AM";  // assuming this is expressed in local time

var millisecondsSinceTheEpoch = (new Date(dateString)).valueOf();  // 1346418000000

var isoString = (new Date(millisecondsSinceTheEpoch)).toISOString();  // 2012-08-31T13:00:00.000Z

// Note: example return values from a computer on U.S. Eastern Daylight Time (-4:00).
```

From [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_valueof_date.asp):

> The valueOf() method returns the primitive value of a Date object.
>
> **Note:** The primitive value is returned as the number of millisecond[s] since midnight January 1, 1970 UTC.

Also see W3Schools for a [comprehensive overview of the Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).

Comment: Hmmm, I'm getting `1346418000000`...what are you getting?

Comment: For me, that converts to ISO string `2012-08-31T16:00:00.000Z`. Is your computer on Pacific Daylight Time?

Comment: Can you show me in a jsfiddle example? I then can post some of my code in a seperate revision

Answer (score 0):

HighStocks expects to get its dates aligned to UTC-midnight date boundary.

Assuming your chart only deals with dates (without the time component) here is a trick you can use:

1. Do `originalDate.getTime()` to get the number of milliseconds since midnight UTC 1/1/1970 , e.g. `1362286800000`.
2. Divide the number of milliseconds by `(1000*60*60*24)` to get the number of **days** since midnight UTC 1/1/1970 e.g. `15767.208333333334`.
3. Do `Math.round()` to round the number to the nearest UTC midnight, e.g. `15767`.
4. Multiply the number by `(1000*60*60*24)` to get it back into the milliseconds scale e.g. `1362268800000`.

Here is the final formula:

```
var utcMidnight=new Date(Math.round(anyZoneMidnight.getTime()/86400000)*86400000)
```